# Non-task-based interfaces and DDD

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

What should we do in case when we have UI that's not task based with tasks corresponding to our entity methods which, in turn, correspond to ubiquitous language?

For example, lets say we have a domain model for `WorkItem` that has properties: `StartDate, DueDate, AssignedToEmployeeId, WorkItemType, Title, Description, CreatedbyEmployeeId`.

Now, some things can change with the `WorkItem` and broken down, it boils to methods like:

```
WorkItem.ReassignToAnotherEmployee(string employeeId)
WorkItem.Postpone(DateTime newDateTime)
WorkItem.ExtendDueDate(DateTime newDueDate)
WorkItem.Describe(string description)
```

But on our UI side there is just one form with fields corresponding to our properties and a single `Save` button. So, CRUD UI. Obviously, that leads to have a single CRUD REST API endpoint like `PUT domain.com/workitems/{id}`.

Question is: how to handle requests that come to this endpoint from the domain model perspective?

**OPTION 1**

Have CRUD like method `WorkItem.Update(...)`? (this, obviously, defeats the whole purpose of ubiquitous language and DDD)

**OPTION 2**

Application service that is called by endpoint controller have method `WorkItemsService.Update(...)` but within that service we call each one of the domain models methods that correspond to ubiquitous language? something like:

```
public class WorkItemService {
...

public Update(params) {
  WorkItem item = _workItemRepository.get(params.workItemId);

  //i am leaving out check for which properties actually changed
  //as its not crucial for this example
  item.ReassignToAnotherEmployee(params.employeeId);
  item.Postpone(params.newDateTime);
  item.ExtendDueDate(params.newDueDate);
  item.Describe(params.description);

  _workItemRepository.save(item);
  }
}
```

Or maybe some third option?
Is there some rule of thumb here?

[UPDATE]
To be clear, question can be rephrased in a way: Should CRUD-like `WorkItem.Update()` ever become a part of our model even if our domain experts express it in a way *we want to be able update a WorkItem* or should we always avoid it and go for *what does "update" actually mean for the business*?

Comment: I will leave this here https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR

Comment: @PabloRecalde can you please explain how is MediatR relevant for this particular question (which is about DDD models)?

Comment: I think is a better way of doing what you propose as second option. I wouldn’t create the ‘Update’ method on the entity, nor a WorkItemService, but rather an WorkItemUpdateCommand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Is your domain/sub-domain inherently CRUD?

> "if our domain experts express it in a way we want to be able update a
> WorkItem"

If your sub-domain aligns well with CRUD you shouldn't try to force a domain model. CRUD is not an anti-pattern and can actually be the perfect fit for certain sub-domains. CRUD becomes problematic when business experts are expressing rich business processes that are wrongly translated to CRUD UIs & backends by developers, leading to code/UL misalignment.

Note that business processes can also be expensive to discover & model explicitly. Sometimes (e.g. lack of resources) it may be acceptable to let those live in the heads of domain experts. They will drive a simple CRUD UI from paper-based processes as opposed to having the system guide them. CRUD may be perfectly fine here since although processes are complex, we aren't trying to model them in the system which remains simple.

I can't tell whether or not your domain is inherently CRUD, but I just wanted to point out that if it is, then embrace it and go for simpler business logic patterns (Active Record, Transaction Script, etc.). If you find yourself constantly wanting to map every bit of data with a single method call then you may be in a CRUD domain.

### Isolate corruption

If you settle that a domain model will benefit your model, then you should stop corruption from spreading through the system as early as you can. This is done with an [anti-corruption layer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184464/what-is-an-anti-corruption-layer-and-how-is-it-used) which in your case would be responsible for interpreting CRUD calls and transforming them into more meaningful business processes.

The anti-corruption layer should sit between the parts of the system you want to protect and the legacy/misbehaving/etc part. That would be option #2. In this case the anti-corruption code will most likely have to compare the current state with the new state to try and figure out what changes were done and how to correlate these to more explicit business processes.

Comment: thank you, your answer is extremely valuable! my problem atm is that 97% of specs are very specific and is a perfect fit for ddd. there is 3% that is expressed like: "update work item" (by same people making those 97% of specific requirements). so, anti-corruption layer makes perfect sense. it might be late so i'm slower but i couldn't understand this sentence even after reading it a few times: *"If you find yourself constantly wanting to map every bit of data with a single method call then you may be in a CRUD domain."* could you please just explain that sentence a bit? thanks!

Comment: Yes, I mean that if for every command data member, you have a corresponding `aggregate.changeX`, `aggregate.setX`, etc. then you **may** be in a CRUD domain. Rich business operations tends to be less fine-grained than that, such as `aggregate.changeContactInformation(contactInfo)` rather than `aggregate.changePhoneNumber(...); aggregate.changeEmail(..); ` etc. Also note that some business use cases can be CRUD. If that 3% is CRUD then put that update method on that AR, end of story. Dont try to overcomplicate things if business experts themselves have no better way of expressing it.

Comment: And if you want to express it differently then, speak to those experts and ask questions to understand what that process really is about. The anti-corruption layer will be helpful in your case when you know the process, but the client is misbehaving by not making it explicit.

Comment: i think your last comment nailed it perfectly. thanks a bunch!

Comment: @deezg Glad I could help! Let me know what you ended up doing, whatever path you choose :)

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, option 1 is pretty much against the ruleset. Additional offering a generic `update` is no good to the clients of your domain enitity.

I would go with a 2ish option: having an Application level service but reflecting the UL to it. Your controller would need to call a meaningful application service method with a meaningful parameter/command that changes the state of a Domain model.

I always try to think from the view of a client of my Service/Domain Model Code. As this client i want to know exactly what i call. Having a CRUD like Update is counter intiuitiv and doesn't help you to follow the UL and is more confusing to the clients. They would need to know the code behind that update method to know what they are changing.

To your Update: no don't include a generic update (atleast not with the name `Update`) always reflect business rules/processes. A client of your code would never know what i does.

In terms if this is a specific business process that gets triggered from a specific controller api endpoint you can call it that way. Let's say your `Update` is actually the business process `DoAWorkItemReassignAndPostponeDueToEmployeeWentOnVacation()` then you could bulk this operation but don't go with the generic Update. Always reflect UL.

Comment: `DoAWorkItemReassignAndPostponeDueToEmployeeWentOnVacation()` - now, that was a very creative way of thinking! haven't think of it at all. thanks for this answer!